# What's the difference between declaration of an int with int keyword or with @property (nonatomic, assign)?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I just want to know what is the difference between writing this :

```
@interface Monster : CCSprite

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *life;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int color;

- (id)initWithFile:(NSString *)file hp:(int)life:(NSString *)color;

@end
```

**and this :**

```
@interface Monster : CCSprite{
    NSString *life;
    int color;
}
- (id)initWithFile:(NSString *)file hp:(int)life:(NSString *)color;

@end
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why would you use an ivar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086736/why-would-you-use-an-ivar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** when you add a property, the class that invoked itself can have access to it. Example

LevelClass alloc and init your Monster class and it has access to his property like this

```
Monster *monsterIstance = [[Monster alloc] init];
NSLog(@" monster life = %@", monsterIstance.life);
```

and once you use @property with @synthesize you automatically generates `set` and `get` code.

```
self.life = @"text";
```

is equal to

```
[self setlife: @"text"];
```

**Long answer:** check this out [when-to-use-properties-in-objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194281/when-to-use-properties-in-objective-c) and [why-would-you-use-an-ivar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086736/why-would-you-use-an-ivar)

and you should also read **[this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1)** tutorial from Ray Wenderlich site that it will explain a lot about arc / property etc